# Wifi communication only

Tags: android, wifi, communication, 3g, restriction

I need to communicate over htttp or https from an android, and I need a settings for my app "wifi only". It's a restriction for the communication. How to implement such a thing? I cannot find any information on AndroidHttpClient works only with Wifi - or 3G as well, and how to restrict it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will check for wifi connection.

```
 public static boolean hasWIFIConnection(Context context)
                    {
                        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                        NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                        if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected())
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
return false;

        }
```

Comment: You can check if WIFI connection available and accordingly restrict.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard about the `setNetworkPreference(int preference)` method in the [`ConnectivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) service. Although it is poorly documented, it appears this method can be used with integer constants which represents a *network type*.

You can find references to such constants in the ConnectivityManager class :

- [TYPE_MOBILE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#TYPE_MOBILE)
- [TYPE_WIFI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#TYPE_WIFI)
- ...

I would start digging this way.

EDIT :

You will need to be granted the folowing permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) 
{
    if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
        if (ni.isConnected())
            haveConnectedWifi = true;
    if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
        if (ni.isConnected())
            haveConnectedMobile = true;}
```

Comment: Thanks all the answers, these are good help. Using them I can check if there is a wifi connected or not. But how can I order the AndroidHttpClient to use wifi or not? Or it is useless to take care about it? If there is no Wifi simply show an alert dialog and perform no communication?

Comment: before calling httpclient check this condition. if wifi not available then show alert otherwise simply proceed.

Answer (score 0):

starting from 23 getNetworkInfo is deprecated, use getActiveNetworkInfo

```
    public boolean hasWIFIConnection()
{
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) ContextProvider.getInstance().getApplication().getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) && activeNetwork.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```